# How to programmatically change the scale of a canvas?

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas

Given a canvas object:

```
MainCanvas = new Canvas();
MainCanvas.Name = "myCanvas";
MainCanvas.Height = 100;
MainCanvas.Width = 100;
```

How can I set its scale(`x` and `y`) via code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
ScaleTransform scale = new ScaleTransform(MainCanvas.LayoutTransform.Value.M11 * ScaleRate, MainCanvas.LayoutTransform.Value.M22 * ScaleRate);
MainCanvas.LayoutTransform = scale;
MainCanvas.UpdateLayout();
```

Comment: The width and the height of the canvas are mapped to the unit in the Transorm object.
The correct rescaling comand would be: ScaleTransform scale = new ScaleTransform(myCanvas.LayoutTransform.Value.M11 * ScaleRate, myCanvas.LayoutTransform.Value.M22 * ScaleRate)